# How do i remove a embedded document

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

I am trying to remove a player from this structure.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "51043d468ead0e0757000006" ),
  "active" : true,
  "created" : 1359232326,
  "difficulty" : 0,
  "map" : { "$ref" : "Map",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "5103c0228ead0e3764000000" ),
    "$db" : "fantasytd" },
  "mode" : "coop",
  "players" : [ 
    { "$ref" : "User",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "50d83abf038054b560000000" ),
      "$db" : "fantasytd" }, 
    { "$ref" : "User",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "50d83abf038054b560000000" ),
      "$db" : "fantasytd" }, 
    { "$ref" : "User",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "50d83abf038054b560000000" ),
      "$db" : "fantasytd" }, 
    { "$ref" : "User",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "50d83abf038054b560000000" ),
      "$db" : "fantasytd" } ],
 "title" : "testgame" }
```

I have tried with

```
$db->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update()
        ->field('id')->equals($gameId)
        ->field('players.$id')->equals($userId)
        ->pull('players.$.assets')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

But it won't do the trick, sadly the documentation for Doctrine MongoDB is very trimmed :/

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as all the players in the array are the same, this should do:

To remove the last player in the list:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$pop: {players: 1}})
```

To remove the first player in the list:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$pop: {players: -1}})
```

(replace "coll" with your collection name).

I assume though that this is not what you want, so I'll add some more players, so that it's easier to see when things disappear:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$push: {players: {$ref: "User", $id: ObjectId("50d83abf038054b560000001")}}})
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$push: {players: {$ref: "User", $id: ObjectId("50d83abf038054b560000002")}}})
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$push: {players: {$ref: "User", $id: ObjectId("50d83abf038054b560000003")}}})
```

You can see the changes with this command:

```
db.coll.find({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}).pretty()
```

To remove, for example, the 3rd player in the array, you can first set the player sub document to null, then remove the null:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$unset: {"players.3": 1}})
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$pull: {players: null}})
```

Or to remove all players with a specific $ref and $id:

```
db.coll.update({_id: ObjectId("51043d468ead0e0757000006")}, {$pull: {players: {$ref: "User", $id: ObjectId("50d83abf038054b560000000")}}})
```

Comment: Could you give an example using the Doctrine Query builder? This is really the big issue. :) Thx thought.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, making a remove method in my Game Document.

```
  public function removePlayer($playerId)
  {
    foreach($this->players as $index => $player) {
      if($player->getId() == $playerId) {
        unset($this->players[$index]);
      }
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

After this method is called, i simply do a flush(), and magic!